# Way to create dll in console

Tags: c++, dll, console

Is there any way in C++ to create a DLL in console **without** using any IDE, such as Visual Studio?

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/705563/14955

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you need the environment configured for a compiler. For example, Microsoft's Visual Studio has a Programs shortcut that does, called `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)` for example. This opens a console with environment configured for the compiler. You can then use `cl.exe` and `link.exe`, and provide the appropriate flags.

Simplest command-line for building a DLL:

> cl.exe /LD main.cpp

Run `cl.exe /?` and `link.exe /?` for a list of flags or see the [C/C++ Building Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91621w01(v=vs.80).aspx)
 online.

Comment: I edited with example of code. To create dll of _func_ I should run `cl.exe /LD func.cpp func.h`. Right?

Comment: @Michael, don't add the `.h`. Note this will _not_ automatically export the `func` function from the DLL. See [Exporting from a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: @Michael, ask a new question. It will get more attention and the edited question is different from the original.

Comment: Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333788/error-with-compiling-dll-with-intel-compiler