# Error with compiling DLL with intel compiler

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, compiler-construction, intel

I'm trying to compile DLL from console, without using any IDE and faced with next error.

I wrote this code:

**test_dll.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#define DLL_EI __declspec(dllexport)

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdreason, LPVOID lpvReserved){
  return 1;
}
extern "C" int DLL_EI func (int a, int b){
  return a + b;
}
```

Then compiled with command `icl /LD test_dll.cpp`. And I'm trying to call this `func` from another program:

**prog.cpp**

```
int main(){
  HMODULE hLib;
  hLib = LoadLibrary("test_dll.dll");  
  double (*pFunction)(int a, int b);
  (FARPROC &)pFunction = GetProcAddress(hLib, "Function");
  printf("begin\n");
  Rss = pFunction(1, 2);
}
```

Compile it with `icl prog.cpp`. Then I run it, and it fails with standard window *"Program isn't working"*. Maybe there is a *segmentation fault* error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a quick glance GetProcAddress should be called with your function name, not "Function". But add some proper error detection code after each call so you can see where it fails.

Comment: You want to use error handling and a debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that both `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` succeed, in this case they definitely will not as the exported function is called `func`, not `"Function"` as specified in the argument to `GetProcAddress()` meaning the function pointer will be `NULL` when the attempt to invoke it is made.

The signature of the function pointer also does not match the signature of the exported function, the exported function returns an `int` and the function pointer is expecting a `double`.

For example:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(int, int);

HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary("test_dll.dll");
if (hLib)
{
    func_t pFunction = (func_t)GetProcAddress(hLib, "func");
    if (pFunction)
    {
        Rss = pFunction(1, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        // Check GetLastError() to determine
        // reason for failure.
    }
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
}
else
{
    // Check GetLastError() to determine
    // reason for failure.
}
```